# How do I fix broken LibreOffice packages

Tags: package-management, libreoffice, error-handling

I have "broken packages" but when I attempt to fix them in Synaptic Package Manager, I get this error message:

```
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 files list file for package `libreoffice-calc' contains empty filename
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
A package failed to install.  Trying to recover:
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-writer:
 libreoffice-writer depends on libreoffice-core (= 1:3.6.2~rc2-0ubuntu4); however:
  Version of libreoffice-core on system is 1:3.6.2~rc2-0ubuntu3.
 libreoffice-writer depends on libreoffice-base-core (= 1:3.6.2~rc2-0ubuntu4); however:
  Version of libreoffice-base-core on system is 1:3.6.2~rc2-0ubuntu3.

dpkg: error processing libreoffice-writer (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: error processing libreoffice-base-core (--configure):
 Package is in a very bad inconsistent state - you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration.
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-calc:
 libreoffice-calc depends on libreoffice-core (= 1:3.6.2~rc2-0ubuntu4); however:
  Version of libreoffice-core on system is 1:3.6.2~rc2-0ubuntu3.
 libreoffice-calc depends on libreoffice-base-core (= 1:3.6.2~rc2-0ubuntu4); however:
  Version of libreoffice-base-core on system is 1:3.6.2~rc2-0ubuntu3.

dpkg: error processing libreoffice-calc (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libreoffice-writer
 libreoffice-base-core
 libreoffice-calc
```

The `sudo apt-get install -f` command gives me this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libreoffice-base-core libreoffice-core libreoffice-draw libreoffice-gnome
  libreoffice-gtk libreoffice-impress libreoffice-math python-uno
Suggested packages:
  libreoffice-base libreoffice-evolution
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libreoffice-base-core libreoffice-core libreoffice-draw libreoffice-gnome
  libreoffice-gtk libreoffice-impress libreoffice-math python-uno
8 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 196 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/36.8 MB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 files list file for package `libreoffice-calc' contains empty filename
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

Using `sudo apt-get purge libreoffice*` followed by `sudo apt-get install libreoffice` give me:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libreoffice : Depends: libreoffice-core (= 1:3.6.2~rc2-0ubuntu4) but 1:3.6.2~rc2-0ubuntu3 is to be installed
               Depends: libreoffice-base but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: ttf-dejavu but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libreoffice-java-common (>= 1:3.6.2~rc2~) but it is not going to be installed
 libreoffice-calc : Depends: libreoffice-core (= 1:3.6.2~rc2-0ubuntu4) but 1:3.6.2~rc2-0ubuntu3 is to be installed
                    Depends: libreoffice-base-core (= 1:3.6.2~rc2-0ubuntu4) but 1:3.6.2~rc2-0ubuntu3 is to be installed
 libreoffice-writer : Depends: libreoffice-core (= 1:3.6.2~rc2-0ubuntu4) but 1:3.6.2~rc2-0ubuntu3 is to be installed
                      Depends: libreoffice-base-core (= 1:3.6.2~rc2-0ubuntu4) but 1:3.6.2~rc2-0ubuntu3 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I have NO IDEA what to do.

Comment: Could you please share the output of 'sudo apt-get install -f' command. This command fixs broken packages.

Comment: sure, I can do that!

Comment: What does running `sudo apt-get install libreoffice-core` say? It's likely there's another package behind that that's causing issues, I think.
Also, try running `sudo apt-get -f install`, like it says at the bottom of the last log.

Comment: try running `sudo apt-get update` before install.

Comment: what should I do after `sudo apt-get update`?

Comment: Also, possible duplicate of [Broken Package Manager? The suggested "apt-get -f install" is failing!](http://askubuntu.com/questions/171038/broken-package-manager-the-suggested-apt-get-f-install-is-failing?rq=1), maybe?

Comment: `sudo apt-get purge libreoffice*`, `sudo apt-get update`, `sudo apt-get install libreoffice`

Answer (score 6):

Try doing `sudo apt-get purge libreoffice*`

Then do `sudo apt-get install libreoffice`

---

If it finds dependence problems:

Type

`sudo apt-get purge libreoffice*`

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install libreoffice`

Comment: I disagree about randomly enabling PPAs. The libreoffice in quantal should work just fine

Comment: helped solve the problem for me.... after a lots of apt-get autoremove etc....I used sudo aptitude etc.. which gives more details about the possibilities and broken dependencies

Comment: The problem might have been me downloading the latest version of libreoffice while the newer versions of the packages weren't available on my mirror yet

Comment: Based on this answer I did `sudo apt purge libreoffice\*` followed by `sudo apt install libreoffice`.  Voila!  Works!

Answer (score 0):

I found this when I got a fatal error from dpkg with the same symptom - empty list file.  . .
https://serverfault.com/questions/430682/dpkg-warning-files-list-file-for-package-x-missing

I also rm'ed the list file from var/lib.

rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/my_missing_package.list.

then reinstalled

wajig reinstall synaptic

I like wajig - takes away the effort of remembering less often used calls to dkpg and apt

Comment: No, reinstalling Synaptic apparently will not help. Also there is a right way to remove broken package list: `sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/my_missing_package.list && sudo apt-get update`.

Answer (score 0):

This solved it for me:

> sudo apt-get purge libreoffice*

A complain stating missing dependencies appeared and suggested to run

> sudo apt-get -f install

which I did.
Then again:

> sudo apt-get purge libreoffice*

followed by:

> sudo apt-get install libreoffice