# `libqapt-runtime' contains empty filename error while updating

Tags: command-line, apt, updates, 64-bit

Whenever I try to update Ubuntu 12.10, it always gets interrupted by this error:

```
files list file for package `libqapt-runtime' contains empty filename
```

I have tried to install with apt-get as well and that gets interrupted by the same error.

Comment: What are the commands that you are entering? Could you past **all** the output of your commands, upload it in paste.ubuntu.com and link it here?

Comment: here it is.  http://paste.ubuntu.com/5705028/

Comment: Enter this command: `sudo apt-get install libqapt-runtime --reinstall` and tell me your results.

Comment: If that doesn't work, you could try with the procedures mentioned in [this post](http://askubuntu.com/a/229403/62483), replacing `libreoffice` with `libqapt-runtime`.

Comment: ok, i have tried that command and i tried the ones on the other post but it does not seem to work, here is my log: http://paste.ubuntu.com/5706618/

Comment: Enter the next command and show me your results: `cd / && find -name "libqapt-runtime*" -print`

Comment: here is my output: http://paste.ubuntu.com/5708600/

Comment: Sorry, this is the correct command: `cd / && sudo find -name "libqapt-runtime*" -print`

Comment: ok, here is my output with the corrected command: http://paste.ubuntu.com/5708621/

Comment: Now delete the `.deb` file and update the system: `sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/libqapt-runtime_1.4.1-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

Comment: ok, i tried that command. It seemed to have deleted the file, but it still displays the same error: http://paste.ubuntu.com/5708720/

Comment: And do you get an output/result when you enter `cd / && sudo find -empty -name "libqapt-runtime*" -print` <-- this command is different 'cause the `-empty` parameter

Comment: no, i do not get an output from that command.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8342/discussion-between-lucio-and-roger-parish-iii)

Comment: im in the chat.